# Convert value between 0 and 1 to hexadecimal

Tags: android, colors, alpha, hex

In an App I am working on, I am trying to create a utility method. The idea of this method is that it takes an int of the form #RRGGBB and a float between 0 and 1 that describes the alpha value of the color. The method should then return a new int of the form #AARRGGBB. The utility method currently looks like this:

```
public static int colorWithAlpha(int color, float alpha) {
    // Somehow convert alpha value between 0 and 1 to hexadecimal
    return color;
}
```

How can I convert a value between 0 and 1 for alpha to a hexadecimal value for alpha, that I can prepend to the color int?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static int colorWithAlpha(int color, float alpha) {
    return color | ((int)(alpha*255)<<24);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// you get the decimal value of the alpha here  
int alphaInt = (int)(alpha * 255);  
// check that the input color has no alpha ("left 8-bit-section" is 0)
bool colorAlreadyHasAlpha = (color & 0xff000000) == 0   

if((alphaInt <= 255 || alphaInt >= 0) && !colorAlreadyHasAlpha){
    // now add it to the "left 8-bit-section" of the integer
    return color |= alphaInt << 24;       
}
else{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("color already has alpha, or provided alpha value is invalid");
}
```